# Selenium - Reference Inner element and obtain its value

Tags: python, selenium

I've been trying to automate some testing based on data contained in an Inner TAG within a SPAN tag. Here's what it looks like:

```
<span class="noqty" tooltip-append-to-body="false" tooltip-is-open="true" uib-tooltip="THIS IS THE TARGET"></span>
```

Currently, I'm reaching this span class through XPATH:

```
//*[@id="content-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span[3]/span/span
```

My question is, how do I reference the "uib-tooltip" and access its value. I've searched around for quite some time but it seems I don't know what to google for exactly.

Would appreciate some advice on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
.get_attribute("uib-tooltip")
```

Or if your trying to get an element based off its uib value use.

```
//span[@uib-tooltip='']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The .get_attribute("uib-tooltip")  worked like a charm.